# Confusion about definition of cycle

Tags: graph-theory, definition

It is said a bipartite graph is such a graph whose set of vertices can be divided into two disjoint parts and for every edge on the graph, a vertex in either set can be found that makes up said edge.

It's also said that a graph being bipartite is equivalent to it containing only even length cycles.

It's not said what exactly constitutes a cycle, though. Well, a set notation is given and intuitively it's understood, aswell. A cycle is what it sounds like: a cycle. You start from somewhere and you end up at the exact same place.

A bipartite graph need not contain any cycle. Do we then say it contains a cycle of length $0$? (even length).

Comment: Probably a better way to say it would be to say that being bipartite is equivalent to NOT containing odd length cycles. The existence of cycles in general is not necessary for a bipartite graph.

Comment: To say that a graph contains "only even cycles" does not mean that it has any cycles at all, it just means that whatever cycles it does have,** if any**, must be even. Put more plainly: a graph is bipartite if and only if it has **no odd cycles**.

Comment: ah yes, that's a lot better. That's the danger in trying to reword something and not thinking of why the initial phrasing was chosen in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is corresponding information from the classic *[Graph Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201410338)* by F. Harary which might be helpful:

> - A *bipartite graph* $G$ is a graph whose vertex set $V$ can be partitioned into two subsets $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that every edge of $G$ joins $V_1$ with $V_2$.
>
>   For example the graph on the left hand side below with vertices
>     \begin{align*}
>   V=V_1\cup V_2\qquad\qquad V_1=\{A_1,A_3,A_5,A_7\},\quad V_2=\{A_2,A_4,A_6,A_8\}
>   \end{align*} is represented on the right hand side to clearly display the fact that it is a bipartite graph.

[image]

> - **Theorem:** A graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if all its cycles are even.
>
>   *Proof:* If $G$ is bipartite, then its vertex set $V$ can be partitioned into two sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ so that every edge of $G$ joins a vertex of $V_1$ with a vertex of $V_2$. Thus every cycle $A_1A_2\cdots A_nA_1$ in $G$ necessarily has its oddly subscripted vertices in $V_1$, say, and the others in $V_2$, so that its length $n$ is even.
>
>   For the converse, we assume, without loss of generality, that $G$ is connected (for otherwise we can consider the components of $G$ separately). Take any node $A_1\in V$, and let $V_1$ consist of $A_1$ and all points at even distance from $A_1$, while $V_2=V\setminus V_1$.
>
>   Since all the cycles of $G$ are even, every edge of $G$ joins a vertex of $V_1$ with a vertex of $V_2$. For suppose there is an edge $BC$ joining two vertices $B$ and $C$ of $V_1$. Then the union of the shortest path from $A_1$ to $B$ and the shortest path from $A_1$ to $C$ together with the edge $BC$ contains an odd cycle, a contradiction.
>
>   $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box$

Comment: wow, a lot more than I bargained for. Thanks, mate :)

Comment: @AlvinLepik: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: I'd like to also point out that if BC is an edge that connects to vertices from set V_1, then that is an immediate contradiction with the choice of the set.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: I agree. In fact the reasoning in the proof *is* a formulation of this immediate contradiction by using the construction principle of $V_1$ and starting the argumentation from $A_1$.

Comment: a more interesting case comes from assuming $BC$ connects two vertices from $V_2$. Then due to connectedness we have a third (but do we?) vertex in $V_2$ and then the edge $BC$ would complete a cycle of odd length, a contradiction.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: We assume all cycle lengths are even. If $BC$ is an edge with vertices in $V_2$ then per construction the distance from $A_1$ to $B$ is odd as well as the distance from $A_1$ to $C$, implying the length of the cycle $A_1-B-C-A_1$ is odd in contradiction to the assumption that each cycle length is even.